# Food ordering system for restaurants

Tags: web-apps

I need an online ordering system for my chain of restaurants (paid or free).

The features required are:

- mobile ordering
- food delivery app
- CMS management tools

Comment: Did you look on https://sourceforge.net ?

Comment: yeah. But Can't find all-in-one food ordering system ( food ordering, delivery app, multi restaurant with admin control )

Comment: @PriyaKumar an old request, but curious as to what solution you went with. I have done something related in past where android tablet/phone app used for ordering in restaurant. Wrote an interface for it so that all orders are sent to a drupal-based CMS site. The site has all products (menus) etc, and gets sycned with restaurant tablets. For delivery, users order on same site via web or mobile phone. But we did not have an app for delivery.